# IE11 clears password fields on page refresh:

Tags: postback, internet-explorer-11

Happens only in IE (Chrome and Firefox, no issues... go figure)

I have a page where customer's can update their details (name, address,password etc.) and everything is working fine, however if the customer submits the form (which also works fine) and then presses the back button all the customer's information will repopulate the form except for the password field.

My boss would like this to repopulate as well, like it does in Chrome and Firefox, but IE won't do it. I'm hoping it's something simple I've missed but I can't see it. I've tried adjusting the lines where the text fields are populated to match the rest of the form, but that just results in empty fields. Code below.

**Page_Load**

```
If TypeOf Session("Customer") Is GPCUser Then
        c = CType(Session("Customer"), GPCUser)
    Else
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx")
    End If
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

        If c.CustomerID > 0 Then
            'populate the table
            lblAccountName.Text = c.AccountName
            txtFirstName.Text = c.FirstName
            txtLastName.Text = c.LastName
            txtEmail.Text = c.Email
            txtAddress.Text = c.Address
            txtSuburb.Text = c.Suburb
            txtCityTown.Text = c.City
            txtPostcode.Text = c.PostCode
            txtPhone.Text = c.Phone
            txtMobile.Text = c.Mobile
            'chkNewsletter.checked = c.Newsletter
            txtPassword.Attributes.Add("value", c.GeneratedPassword)
            txtConfirmPassword.Attributes.Add("value", c.GeneratedPassword)
            'txtPassword.Text = c.GeneratedPassword
            'txtConfirmPassword.Text = c.GeneratedPassword
            Dim subscriptions As ContactSubscriptions = New ContactSubscriptions(c.CustomerID)
            chkGenernalNewsletters.Checked = subscriptions.IsGenernalNewsletters

        End If

    Else

    End If
```

**Update Button**

```
If TypeOf Session("Customer") Is GPCUser Then
        c = CType(Session("Customer"), GPCUser)
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    c.AccountName = lblAccountName.Text
    c.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text
    c.LastName = txtLastName.Text
    c.Email = txtEmail.Text
    c.Address = txtAddress.Text
    c.Suburb = txtSuburb.Text
    c.City = txtCityTown.Text
    c.PostCode = txtPostcode.Text
    c.Phone = txtPhone.Text
    c.Mobile = txtMobile.Text
    'c.Newsletter = chkNewsletter.Checked
    c.GeneratedPassword = txtPassword.Text
    c.CustomerUpdatedRequired = false

    'Update password field
    txtPassword.Attributes.Add("value", c.GeneratedPassword)
    txtConfirmPassword.Attributes.Add("value", c.GeneratedPassword)
    GPCUser.AddUpdateCustomer(c)
    subscriptions.IsGenernalNewsletters = chkGenernalNewsletters.Checked
    subscriptions.Save()

    Session("Customer") = c

    lblMessage.Text = "Your details have been successfully updated."
    pnlUpdateAccount.Visible = False
```

Comment: Ughhhh, I'd expect it to not do that actually. That would freak me out if I pressed back and my password was still there.

Comment: Yeah, me too... but boss's orders.